# Upload multiple files with multiple instances of the same service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm pretty new with the Services api and generally with android networking.

I'm trying to upload more than one big files at the same time (almost). For example user clicks two buttons, one after the other and I start a new service (same service, different instances).

Most of the times, if not all, there is one or more errors. Files don't get uploaded correct. Something else I have also noticed is that when one service instance finishes with uploading and stops, other service stops also.

Am I right with my observations about `Service` class ? Isn't it possible to have more than one instance of the same `Service` at the same time ?

If so, then how am I going to upload simultaneously more than one files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not understanding the Service class well. You should only have one instance of that service. Anyhow, you could have a queue or some data structure inside that service to handle the uploads. You could upload multiple files at the same time just using different threads for uploading tasks.
hope it helps

Comment: Thank's a lot. It's much clearer now. One more question : if I'm going to have different threads for uploading how am I going to know when to call stopSelf() ?

Comment: you can always check if there is an upload running, either by using a mutex or some other sync method! You'll stop the service when there is no uploading thread running. Or, you could just leave the service running, given that is not going to run anything :P